# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthController (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0]

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to add auth controller, to do that I have created auth controller, auth module, and I have imported that to the app module.ts file.. At this time I am getting this error,, How can I solve that?

Auth Controller

```
import {Body, Controller, Injectable, Post, UnauthorizedException} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';


@Controller("login")
export class AuthController {

    constructor(
        @InjectModel("User") private userModel: Model) {

    }

}
```

Auth Module

```
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common'
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { UsersSchema } from './users.schema';
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: "User", schema: UsersSchema
      }
    ])
  ],
  controllers: [
    AuthController
  ]
})

export class AuthModule{

}
```

App Module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CoursesModule } from './courses/courses.module';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose'
import {MONGO_CONNECTION} from './constants'
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CoursesModule,
    AuthModule,
    MongooseModule.forRoot(MONGO_CONNECTION)
]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

error

```
 Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthController (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context
```

Comment: That's the entire error? With what you've shown, I'd expect that to work.

Comment: if I remove constructor from auth controller it works fine.

Comment: It can not find database model of user, Please edit your question and add MongoDb configuration and user model file itself

Comment: @rabbanisarkar right, I get that, but from what you've shown here it should be fine. The `MongooseModule` sets up the token for the `@InjectModel()`. Is that the entirety of the error, or did parts get left out?